# MySQL server installation lacks libmysql.lib

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm trying to write a c++ wrapper for MySQL:

> cannot open input file 'libmysql.lib'

I did install mySQL server but I still don't have libmysql.lib

Comment: (It might help if you link the question where you would comment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these instructions (I am assuming you installed an instance of `MySQL Server`):

- link your project with libmysql.lib
- Ignore the message error "Missing **libmysql.dll**"
- copy **libmysql.dll** to the release folder

Compile and run your program.

Comment: How can you link the project with libmysql.lib if you don't have it?